# Can I make this work without global variables?

Tags: python, logging, import, static, global

## library.py

```
str = '' 
def setStr(input):
   global str
   str = input
def getStr():
   return str
```

Now I can import in modules and update them...

## module1.py

```
import library
import module2

library.setStr('wow')
module2.run()
```

## module2.py

```
import library

def run():
        print(library.getStr())
```

## output

```
wow
```

Is there a way to create the functionality I showed without global calls?

Thanks!

Comment: What will your library do that the python logging library doesn't do, other than looking sloppy?  There are probably thousands of man-hours already invested in the python logging library.  Why do you think you, or anyone for that matter, can "replicate it in a better way"?  Since your only idea is to use a lot of globals (rather than classes and objects), the outlook seems rather bleak.

Comment: I meant I need to make my solution in a better way..I can't use the logging library for my needs unfortunately. I realize my ambiguity in the title. changing now.

Answer (score 0):

> So how do I replicate the way logging works but without global variables for my purposes?

You can't, because [`logging` uses global (module-level) variables to store its configuration](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/logging/__init__.py).  For example, the [root logger](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1669) is kept in a global variable.

(I mean, you could have those variables live at the class level instead of the module level, as is done with `Logger.manager`, but it's the same code smell either way.)

Comment: How? I've gone through the methods code. It never uses a global variable.

Comment: [`root`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1669) is a global variable.  `Logger.manager` is a class variable, basically a global variable in disguise.